# In WCS, can we invoke a controller command from within a jsp ? If yes, please explain the different methods

Tags: websphere, websphere-commerce, wcs

From what I've heard, A controller command can be invoked from within a scriptlet. But I am not sure of other methods. Any code level information would be very helpful.

Comment: What is the use case under which you would want to do this, yes you can, but you shouldn't.  If this is your plan, you are misusing the framework.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. This is just for knowledge sake as this was asked once when we had a discussion on WCS.

Answer (score 0):

You can also try making AJAX call from the JSP to the controller command.

Answer (score 0):

You really shouldn't be directly executing a controller command from within the scriptlet code of a JSP.  You could use AJAX to call a command service.  Or you could use a DataBean Command, though they are really meant to be commands that populate the databean not really call controller commands.  You may also be in a situation that you need to review your use of a controller command, possibly BOD commands would be a better fit if you are wanting to invoke a service from the JSP during the page generation.

Answer (score 0):

You could create your own mapping of your ControllerCommand to REST.

http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSZLC2_7.0.0/com.ibm.commerce.webservices.doc/tasks/twvrestsamplecmd.htm

Then you use the REST tag to run the ControllerCommand.

http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSZLC2_7.0.0/com.ibm.commerce.component-services.doc/refs/rwvwcfresttag.htm

In the new implementation from IBM in FEP8 this will be done locally if possible and will therefor not add any extra network overhead.

Answer (score -1):

By Using Databean also we can invoke controller commands.

```
ex : <wcbase:usebean>
```

Comment: This seems incomplete... care to finish the thought?